# Python: Create a list of directories containing audio files

Tags: python, python-os

```py
import os

path = "."

x = []

list_subfolders_with_paths = []
for  dirs in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        x.append(dir)
            

print(len(x))
```

Comment: By “audio files” do you mean a specific file extension, or a collection of extensions? Or, should the program be extension-agnostic, and cleverly pick out an ‘audio file’?

Comment: I mean path directories , like /storage/emulated/0/DCIM, I want to know if DCIM contains mp3 files , then return true , since I have all of the paths , I'll just loop through to know the ones that contains mp3 files then return true for the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from glob import glob
list_subfolders_with_paths = glob('path/*.mp3')
```

Replace mp3 with audio files extensions and * is for every mp3 file in path.

Comment: Let's say I have a list containing this paths [user/audio, user/music, user/pictures] how do I return True if the paths contain .mp3 files?

Comment: Use "user/*/*.mp4". It will take all sub folder in user and mp4 files inside them

Comment: I don't want to get the audio file name or paths, I just want to know if the directory contains audio files

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of paths all of which have the same root directory, you can use the `recursive` argument from `glob`.

For example:

```
import os
from glob import glob

files = glob(os.path.join('/path/to/dir', '**', '*.mp3'), recursive=True)
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories, subdirectories and symbolic links to directories.

---

#### Directory paths only:

To retrieve a list of directory *paths* which contain the subject files, the following can be used:

```
paths = list(set(map(os.path.dirname, files)))
```

The `map` function is used to get the path for each file listed in the `files` list. The `set` function is used to sub-set the list of directories to *unique* values only. Finally, the `list` function is used to convert the set of directory paths back into a list.

Comment: Will files be the file format i want to check for ? Like .mp3?

Comment: Yes, of course.  The file extension is specified to the `glob` function.  Have a look in the first section of this answer.

Comment: The `files` list created by the first section of the answer is used by the directory-only filter in the second part of the answer.  Slot these two together and you have a solution.  :-)

Comment: Thanks very much, I get it now

Comment: I've clicked on it

Comment: I ran out of data to come online, so I kept working on my own way to solve the problem and that's what I came up with, I couldn't check your reply on time ,so I just replied your answer since I  took your time.

Answer (score 0):

'''python

import os

path = "enter your directory path "

path_dir = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

```
for dir in dirs:
    root_dir= os.path.join(root, dir)
    for v in os.listdir(root_dir):
        if v.endswith(".mp3") or v.endswith(".m4a"):
            if root_dir in path_dir:
                pass
            else:
                path_dir.append(root_dir)
```

'''